# Узнать адрес процесса в памяти

Tags: windows, память

Всем привет. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как я могу узнать адрес в памяти конкретного процесса, `steam.exe`, например?

Comment: Вы о каком именно адресе говорите?

Comment: Вам который адрес? Виртуальный адрес "изнутри" самого процесса или какой-то еще? И, скорее всего, адрес этот вам не нужен: просто так записать в него не выйдет.